# Deleting Widgets(Text,Label,Button) in Tkinter Python Created Using For Loop

Tags: python, function, tkinter

```
def removal():
list = [list for x in panels if not x.grid_remove()]
print(panels)
for ce in panels:
    ce.grid_remove()
    ce
print(panels)

def selectgoodtip():
    i=0
    b=0
    global panel1,panel2,labels,panels,panels2
    for te in selectgoods:
            labels = Label(scrollable_frame, text=te)
            labels.config(font=("Open Sans", 8))
            labels.grid(row=i,column=1,sticky='sw')
            i=i+1
    panels = []
    panels2 = []
    for ce in selectpic:
        pathtophoto = Image.open(ce)
        image1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(pathtophoto)
        panel1 = Label(scrollable_frame, image=image1)
        panel1.image = image1  # keep a reference
        panel1.grid(row=b,column=0)
        panels.append(panel1)
        remove = Image.open("remove1.png")
        image2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(remove)
        panel2 = Button(scrollable_frame, image=image2, bg='#ffffff', relief=FLAT,command=lambda:removal())
        panel2.image = image2  # keep a reference
        panel2.grid(row=b, column=3, sticky='ne')
        panels2.append(panel2)
        b=b+1
        #selectpic.clear()
#Operation Tips
#Product selection processing
def addselectfood(name,money,pic):
    global selectmoney,selectgoods,selectpic
    if len(selectgoods)<17:
        selectgoods.append(name)
        selectmoney= selectmoney+money
        selectpic.append(pic)
        selectgoodtip()
```

[Example Image of what i mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLVIf.png)

I would Like The x button Panel2 to delete itself, panel1 and labels created in the for loop using the function removal so it deletes the item on the side panel to remove it? So each X button will remove the item it is resposible for?

Comment: Have you tried simply saving the widgets in a list, and then iterating over the list?

Answer (score 0):

`lambda` to the rescue! This is a simple program I made just for a reference. What you can do is create a local variable of each button, use `lambda` and destroy the widget.

**This is the main line that does the job:** `b2.config(command=lambda x=b1,y=b2: [x.destroy(),y.destroy()])`

```
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
for i in range(10):
    b1=Button(root,text=f"Button {i}")
    b1.grid(row=i,column=1)
    b2=Button(root,text=f"Delete Button {i}")
    b2.grid(row=i,column=2,padx=10)
    b2.config(command=lambda x=b1,y=b2: [x.destroy(),y.destroy()])

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank You So much your the best. I really appreciate the help.

Comment: Welcome @DragonKing, hope it solves the issue